# grayscale Laplace sharpening implementation

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am  trying to implement Laplace sharpening using C++ , here's my code so far:

```
img = imread("cow.png", 0);
Mat convoSharp() {

    //creating new image
    Mat res = img.clone();
    for (int y = 0; y < res.rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < res.cols; x++) {
            res.at<uchar>(y, x) = 0.0;
        }
    }

    //variable declaration
    int filter[3][3] = { {0,1,0},{1,-4,1},{0,1,0} };
    //int filter[3][3] = { {-1,-2,-1},{0,0,0},{1,2,1} };
    int height = img.rows;
    int width = img.cols;
    int filterHeight = 3;
    int filterWidth = 3;
    int newImageHeight = height - filterHeight + 1;
    int newImageWidth = width - filterWidth + 1;
    int i, j, h, w;

    //convolution
    for (i = 0; i < newImageHeight; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < newImageWidth; j++) {
            for (h = i; h < i + filterHeight; h++) {
                for (w = j; w < j + filterWidth; w++) {
                    res.at<uchar>(i,j) += filter[h - i][w - j] * img.at<uchar>(h,w);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //img - laplace
    for (int y = 0; y < res.rows; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < res.cols; x++) {

            res.at<uchar>(y, x) = img.at<uchar>(y, x) - res.at<uchar>(y, x);

        }
    }



    return res;
}
```

[image: this is the result]

I don't really know what went wrong, I also tried different filter (1,1,1),(1,-8,1),(1,1,1) and the result is also same (more or less). I don't think that I need to normalize the result because the result is in range of 0 - 255. Can anyone explain what really went wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: `uchar` is too small to hold partial results of filerting operation.

You should create a temporary variable and add all the filtered positions to this variable then check if value of temp is in range `<0,255>` if not, you need to clamp the end result to fit `<0,255>`.

By executing below line

```
res.at<uchar>(i,j) += filter[h - i][w - j] * img.at<uchar>(h,w);
```

partial result may be greater than 255 (max value in `uchar`) or negative (in filter you have -4 or -8). `temp` has to be singed integer type to handle the case when partial result is negative value.

Fix:

```
for (i = 0; i < newImageHeight; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < newImageWidth; j++) {
        int temp = res.at<uchar>(i,j); // added
        for (h = i; h < i + filterHeight; h++) {
            for (w = j; w < j + filterWidth; w++) {
                temp += filter[h - i][w - j] * img.at<uchar>(h,w); // add to temp
            }
        }
        // clamp temp to <0,255>
        res.at<uchar>(i,j) = temp;
    }
}
```

You should also clamp values to `<0,255>` range when you do the subtraction of images.

Comment: Actually, the result of the Laplace can have negative values, clamping them is not good. You need a signed type to hold the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is partially that you’re overflowing your `uchar`, as [rafix07 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678943/7328782), but that is not the full problem.

The Laplace of an image contains negative values. It has to. And you can’t clamp those to 0, you need to preserve the negative values. Also, it can values up to 4*255 given your version of the filter. What this means is that you need to use a signed 16 bit type to store this output.

But there is a simpler and more efficient approach!

You are computing `img - laplace(img)`. In terms of convolutions (`*`), this is `1 * img - laplace_kernel * img = (1 - laplace_kernel) * img`. That is to say, you can combine both operations into a single convolution. The `1` kernel that doesn’t change the image is `[(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,0)]`. Subtract your Laplace kernel from that and you obtain `[(0,-1,0),(-1,5,-1),(0,-1,0)]`.

So, simply compute the convolution with that kernel, and do it using `int` as intermediate type, which you then clamp to the `uchar` output range as shown by rafix07.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/NOZpG3L)  is that what you meant ? convoS2 is using [(0,-1,0),(-1,5,-1),(0,-1,0)] kernel and convoS1 is using kernel that I stated above. anyway thanks your your input , really appreciate it !

Comment: @Welly: It’s hard to tell, with the JPEG compression artifacts. Does it give a sharper impression than the original? Does it give a sharper impression than the original result? If so, then yes, that’s what I meant.

Comment: Yup , in fact it does. Thank you very much mate , have a good day !